# ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'crm.activity'

Tags: python, crm, odoo, odoo-9

I am using crm module, but i have a problem. Every time i change stage of lead with activity column not null, I always get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'crm.activity
```

Could someone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: show your code!

Comment: Please create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the data of crm.activity model into any other model.
For doing this, must be the type of both these data same.

For Example:
If you link two field, one from crm.activity and other from account.account than It raise same above error.